Caching of RUN commands in Docker
Will result of command be cached?
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y <package> && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

So update && install will happen only ounce?

Subject to the usual Docker rules here – nothing is cached if the text of the RUN statement changes or if the image up to this point isn't identical.  Is there a more specific problem you're running into?

Actually no. Just realized this is not that useful question.

Run is subject to Docker rules. So if command string does not change itself and anything above is cached, this run command will be cached too.
Use it after something changed, like files copied to Docker or use cache busting pattern.
